# Quartz Scheduler in my ASP.NET MVC application executes job only after refreshing the webpage/application at IIS server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, quartz.net

So I am using Quartz Scheduler for my ASP.NET MVC application in order to schedule a job for writing a file. This job can be triggered hourly, daily, weekly etc depending on user requirements when he configures the job from a webpage.

Code in this link:
[How to check if a particular job is running in quartz scheduler c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53308576/how-to-check-if-a-particular-job-is-running-in-quartz-scheduler-c-sharp)

However I discarded my stop() method to make the configured job run forever. I am able to get the jobs running successfully locally, but I can see the file job executing only after I refresh the web application running at IIS server.

At first, I was calling the start() of my job scheduler at Application_start() of Global.asax.cs file in order to resume the job when web application starts.

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        using (var db = new M3DBContext())
        {
            //db.Configurations is a table in my db
            var file_loc = (from c in db.Configurations where c.ConfigurationKey == "file_location" select c.ConfigurationValue).Single();
            var freq = (from c in db.Configurations where c.ConfigurationKey == "frequency" select c.ConfigurationValue).Single();
            var delim = (from c in db.Configurations where c.ConfigurationKey == "delimiter" select c.ConfigurationValue).Single();
            var datetime = (from c in db.Configurations where c.ConfigurationKey == "datetime" select c.ConfigurationValue).Single();

            //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(file_loc + " " + freq + " " + delim + " " + datetime);
            JobScheduler js = new JobScheduler(datetime,freq);
            if (!(file_loc.Equals("default") || freq.Equals("default") || delim.Equals("default") || datetime.Equals("1970-1-1")))
            {
                js.start();
            }
        }
    }
```

But the main requirement is to make the scheduled job run forever at configured intervals in spite of web application being open/close/refreshed/unrefreshed. My job doesn't run when the web applciation is closed and the IIS is still on.

How can I make my application's quartz scheduler to run forever in IIS inspite of web application is opened/closed/refreshed/unrefreshed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Application_Start` is only run after the first HTTP request and, indeed, after a IIS recycling, JobScheduler will not be run until a new request triggers the web server. You cannot change this behaviour.

However, you can make IIS run a default request after the recycling by enabling [preloadEnabled](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vijaysk/2012/10/11/iis-8-whats-new-website-settings/) on IIS setting of your web site. It will trigger `Application_Start`.

Comment: Can't I remove the scheduler.start() from Application_start and move it to the controller which is interacting with Job Configurations View?

Comment: Does your method ensure job is going to run in background without refreshing web application?

Comment: I will be useless as Application_Start is run before any controllers. So to fulfill your requirements, it should stay in Application_Start and you should add preloadEnabled on IIS settings

Answer (score 2):

This is the exact reason why scheduling things in a web host is dicey at best, and honestly not recommended. If you have jobs that need to run on a regular schedule, regardless of web traffic, the best option is always a stand-alone service to handle the background jobs. It can live on the same server, but services are designed with high uptime, and are tailor made to stay alive and execute things in the background.

Having said that, if you for some reason *have* to have this as a part of your web application, then you will need to turn on the feature to have the application always running. As mentioned above you will want to turn on preload and turn on always on mode of IIS https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vijaysk/2012/10/09/iis-8-whats-new-application-pool-settings/

The only alternative to this is have an outside service access a page(any page) of the application on a regular basis, or on server startup. This could be accomplished as a scheduled task/cron job with a simple curl command to load a page.